# Access a static file using a uri without specifying extension in spring mvc

Tags: java, json, spring, maven

How can I access a static file using URI in Spring MVC and Maven?
I want to access a file **hello.json** via **localhost:8080://project/hello**

Also, how can I set `application/json` mime type?

EDIT:This question is not related with another question **How to serve static content in spring mvc?** As my requirement is access a particular file without specifying its extension.

Comment: put application/json mime type this way :   @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")

Comment: as actually i just want to access a static resource(a json file) by hitting a url like localhost:8080://project/hello , in this way i need to access a file without extension. Please let me know can we solved this issue by using resource mapping in mvc? Since it's just a access call i dont want to execute a controller.

Comment: the main reason for asking such a requirement is to solve the issue as given in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093807/host-apple-app-association-file-in-tomcat-web-server

Please let me know if any of you guys help me out

Comment: try this https://springframework.guru/processing-json-jackson/

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean? if it produces it than what Georges says is true.

Since you're trying to read it you might try:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

you should know this but MediaType comes from the jax-ws rs api that comes as a part of Java EE but also separately. if your response is also JSON, then it would be:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```